# Too big number for repeat range when using regexp_like in where clause

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I tried to run the following query:

```
select * from table where regexp_like('^{{', text_field)
```

And got the following error:

> too big number for repeat range

Thinking perhaps `regexp_like` is confusing `{` for the repeat count operator, I also tried the following variations:

```
select * from table where regexp_like('^\{\{', text_field)
select * from table where regexp_like('^[{][{]', text_field)
select * from table where regexp_like('^[[:punct:]]{2}', text_field)
```

None of which worked. For now, `text_field like '{{'` suffices, but I may want to include a more flexible version of this that would require regular expressions. What's wrong with my approach here? And what does this error message mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the prestodb regex_like function in the wrong way:

```
regexp_like(string, pattern)
```

> Evaluates the regular expression pattern and determines if it is
>   contained within string.  This function is similar to the LIKE
>   operator, expect that the pattern only needs to be contained within
>   string, rather than needing to match all of string. In other words,
>   this performs a contains operation rather than a match operation. You
>   can match the entire string by anchoring the pattern using ^ and $:

```
SELECT regexp_like('1a 2b 14m', '\d+b'); -- true
```